Fluentreports - How to print page number by using ReportBuilder
I am new to both FluentReports and ReportBuilder features. While I can use ReportBuilder to print reports, I have read the documents and demo examples provided by fluentreports.com and found no hints on how to print page numbers on each page footer.
Could anyone provide documents or examples on how to print page numbers using ReportBuilder?
